# Want the prototype method to be extended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    var defaults = {
        test: function () {
            alert('Test');
        }
    };

    function Foo(options) {
        o = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        Foo.prototype.test = o.test;
    }
    Foo.prototype.test = defaults;
```

I want that the test method should be extensible and I want it to be used as:

```
    var f = new Foo({
        test: function() {
            alert('Test2');
        }
    });

    var f1 = new Foo({
        test: function () {
            alert('Test3');
        }
    });

    f.test();//alert(test2) should be called
    f1.test(); //alert(test3) should be called
```

Edit: I am not getting what I have written in the comments as the output.

Comment: Are you just stuck with the problem or something? This sounds suspiciously like "just do the work for me"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're kind of mixing metaphors there. Three options for you:

- Functional
- Simple constructor functions, override per instance (what you were trying to do)
- Reusable prototypical inheritance

### Functional

It sounds like you'd like the form of *functional inheritance* that Douglas Crockford likes, which does away with prototypes in favor of what he calls "maker" functions:

```
var f = makeFoo({
    test: function() {
        alert('Test2');
    }
});

var f1 = makeFoo({
    test: function () {
        alert('Test3');
    }
});

f.test();
f1.test();
```

...where `makeFoo` is:

```
function makeFoo(options) {
    return $.extend({}, makeFoo.defaults, options);
}
makeFoo.defaults = {
    test: function() {
        alert("Default test");
    }
};
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/inufaq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/inufaq/edit)

I'm not a huge fan of it myself, but there are many who are and certainly like most things, it has advantages and disadvantages. One of the advantages is how simple it is.

### Simple constructor functions, override per instance

But you can do it with constructor functions, much as you tried; you apply the options to `this` rather than creating your own separate object:

```
function Foo(options) {
    $.extend(this, options);
}
Foo.prototype.test = function() {
    alert("Default test");
};

var f = new Foo({
    test: function() {
        alert("Test2");
    }
});

var f2 = new Foo({
    test: function() {
        alert("Test3");
    }
});

f.test();
f2.test();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/igonam) | [source](http://jsbin.com/igonam/edit)

### Reusable prototypical inheritance

If you want to go further and have proper hierarchies based on prototypical inheritance (so you can create more than one object with a specific override `test` function), there's more plumbing to do, but you have the advantage that doing things like calling into a "super"'s version of a function can be quite straight-forward. The plumbing is sufficiently complex that I use a library for it, in my case my own library called [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/), but Prototype has something similar called [`Class`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/) and there are several others out there.

When doing prototypical inheritance, you have constructor functions and then construct instances with them. The above might look something like this with `Lineage`:

```
var ParentFoo = Lineage.define(function(p) {
    p.test = function() {
      alert("Default test");
    };
});

var FooChild1 = Lineage.define(ParentFoo, function(p) {
    p.test = function() {
      alert("Test2");
    };
});

var FooChild2 = Lineage.define(ParentFoo, function(p) {
    p.test = function() {
      alert("Test3");
    };
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ojebuh) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ojebuh/edit)

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just do this?

```
function Foo(options) {
    o = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this.test = o.test;
}
```